# Is there any way to show center of the object in fabric js and re-locate it anywhere on the object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, fabricjs

I am working with react js and fabric js. Now while I am trying to transform the object I need to show the center coordinates of the object.

**Screenshot:** [Example of the canvas object with center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21adk.jpg)

The blue-colored center-point can be relocatable so we can drag it anywhere on the object.
While we drag that center point and zoom or scale the object it takes that point as center and scale around it.

**Code for selecting the object:**

```
let canvas = this._canvas;
    canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
    canvas.discardActiveObject();
    canvas.forEachObject(
        o =>
            (o.selectable = o.evented = o.hasControls = o.hasBorders = true)
    );
    
    var sel = new fabric.ActiveSelection(canvas.getObjects(), {
        canvas: canvas,
        hasControls: true,
        hasBorders: true,
        hasRotatingPoint: true,
        selectable: true,
        centeredRotation:true
    });
    canvas.setActiveObject(sel);
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
```